# Format an input field for US number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a small issue with my code and I am not able to crack it, the format I want is
+1 (888) 123-4567   . However I have achieved this (544)-646-4646 format. But I am unable to figure how can i get +1 already written and when someone types number the remaining should be formatted as the above example.

so in simple words I need +1 to be already typed and rest when typed by user would give the same format as the code.

Here is the code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  /***phone number format***/
  $(".phone-format").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
      return false;
    }
    var curchr = this.value.length;
    var curval = $(this).val();
    if (curchr == 3 && curval.indexOf("(") <= -1) {
      $(this).val("(" + curval + ")" + "-");
    } else if (curchr == 4 && curval.indexOf("(") > -1) {
      $(this).val(curval + ")-");
    } else if (curchr == 5 && curval.indexOf(")") > -1) {
      $(this).val(curval + "-");
    } else if (curchr == 9) {
      $(this).val(curval + "-");
      $(this).attr('maxlength', '16');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<input class="phone-format" value=""  type="text" placeholder="Phone Number">
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: keep value = '+1 ' and manipualte further

Comment: I did, that didnt work.

Comment: If any of these answers below solved your issue, it would be good to mark this question as resolved by upvoting and marking answer as resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<input class="phone-format" value="+1 "  type="text" placeholder="Phone Number">
</body>


</html>
```

And in js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  /***phone number format***/
  $(".phone-format").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
      return false;
    }
    var curchr = this.value.length;
    var curval = $(this).val();
    if (curchr == 6 && curval.indexOf("(") <= -1) {
      $(this).val(curval.substring(0, 2) + " (" + curval.substring(3) + ")" + "-");
    } else if (curchr == 7 && curval.indexOf("(") > -1) {
      $(this).val(curval + ")-");
    } else if (curchr == 8 && curval.indexOf(")") > -1) {
      $(this).val(curval + "-");
    } else if (curchr == 12){
      $(this).val(curval + "-");
      $(this).attr('maxlength', '16');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the [jquery input mask plugin](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/)

You just need to specify the mask/format you want your input to be in and it does the job.

```js
$(window).load(function()
{
   $('#phone').inputmask({"mask": "+1(999) 999-9999"}); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.1.62/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='phone' />
```